# display image on middle of div

Tags: css

I was looking the way to create image view as have Facebook or Google Plus but i can't put the image at middle of `div`.

This is my code:

```
.overflow {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.overflow .left-img-box,.overflow .right-content-box {
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
}

.overflow .left-img-box {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70%;
}

.overflow .right-content-box {
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 30%;
}

.overflow .left-img-box img {
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

You can see the example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/N6md8/5/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something css like:

```
img {
margin:auto;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
max-height:100%;
max-width:100%;}
```

reference: http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt

I beleive you can go with position:fixed as well :)

Comment: it wok just if the image have width smaller than height look at example http://fiddle.jshell.net/N6md8/9/

Comment: for info, younger browser can do it through flexbox method : http://fiddle.jshell.net/N6md8/8/ and it can clip image via overflow: http://fiddle.jshell.net/N6md8/12/ and display:table http://fiddle.jshell.net/N6md8/13/

Comment: @Medda86 thanks again it works fine now i hade just to do max-width:100%.